# Row with a vertical picture and a horizontal picture with minimum white space?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to lay out a List of images containing a mix of portrait and landscape images and I would like to minimize white space. For now, I have a column whose children are rows whose children are Flexible whose child are Images:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Flexible(
                      child: Image.network(
                        'https://via.placeholder.com/400x600',
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 8,
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: Image.network(
                        'https://via.placeholder.com/400x600',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Flexible(
                      child: Image.network(
                        'https://via.placeholder.com/600x400',
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 8,
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: Image.network(
                        'https://via.placeholder.com/600x400',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Flexible(
                      child: Image.network(
                        'https://via.placeholder.com/400x600',
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 8,
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: Image.network(
                        'https://via.placeholder.com/600x400',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 8,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Flexible(
                      child: Image.network(
                        'https://via.placeholder.com/600x400',
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 8,
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: Image.network(
                        'https://via.placeholder.com/400x600',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This example project demonstrates all the scenarios I want my layout to handle.

So in an app, I get the following:

[image: Initial layout with a lot of white space]

So as you can see, when a row contains a portrait and a landscape image, the shortest image has a lot of space above and below. And I would like to lay out my images so that the cells of the row are not the same width, but their widths adapt so that the shortest image gets taller and the tallest image gets shorter and they both occupy the full height of the row, without messing with their respective aspect ratios of course.

How can I do that?

By the way, I put together a sample project with the [simplest version of my problem here](https://github.com/sarbogast/image_layout_test).

Answer (score 1):

have you considered using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view) package?

#### Update

if you don't want to use a package, you might try something like this:

```
final List<Widget> _images = [
    Image.network('https://via.placeholder.com/400x600'),
    Image.network('https://via.placeholder.com/400x600'),
    Image.network('https://via.placeholder.com/600x400'),
    Image.network('https://via.placeholder.com/600x400'),
    Image.network('https://via.placeholder.com/400x600'),
    Image.network('https://via.placeholder.com/600x400'),
    Image.network('https://via.placeholder.com/600x400'),
    Image.network('https://via.placeholder.com/400x600'),
  ];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Wrap(
                    runSpacing: 8,
                    children: images
                        .where((element) => images.indexOf(element) % 2 == 0)
                        .toList(),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 8),
                Expanded(
                  child: Wrap(
                    runSpacing: 8,
                    children: images
                        .where((element) => images.indexOf(element) % 2 == 1)
                        .toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

or using list of urls:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> _images = [
    'https://via.placeholder.com/400x600',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/400x600',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/600x400',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/600x400',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/400x600',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/600x400',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/600x400',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/400x600',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: Wrap(
                    runSpacing: 8,
                    children: [
                      for (int index = 0; index < _images.length; index += 2)
                        Image.network(_images[index])
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 8),
                Expanded(
                  child: Wrap(
                    runSpacing: 8,
                    children: [
                      for (int index = 1; index < _images.length; index += 2)
                        Image.network(_images[index])
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: No, I didn't know about it. But I would rather avoid using a package to do that if possible, because in reality, the layout I'm trying to do is in a PDF using dart-pdf. And dart-pdf mirrors most of Flutter's native layout widgets, so if I can do it in native Flutter without a package, I think I can do it in PDF.

Comment: then you might try what Oscar suggested, I'll update my answer with a sample code.

Comment: I tried implementing your suggestion in this branch (https://github.com/sarbogast/image_layout_test/tree/suggestion-samer) but it just gives me all the images in one column

Comment: this is because indexOf retrieve first match, so either use list of Image.network
or iterate inside the children, I will update my answer for the two cases

Comment: so we can't use indexOf with list of strings here, in case of duplicate url, but it should work fine with list of widgets.

Comment: Damn that works, but unfortunately I can't use that one for PDF because there's only one root widget, the big Row, and with dart-pdf, I can't have one widget span over several pages like that. But you answered my initial question.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use the staggered_grid I create the same goal with 2 Columns, left for odd index and right for even index